# BigQuery standrat SQL - view is not being saved

Tags: view, save

I'm using the standart SQL mode in BigQuery.

I'm trying to save a query that run perfectly **as a view**:

[image]

And i'm getting a weird error:

[image]

"Failed to save view. Table name cannot be resolved: project name is missing."

The project name couldn't be missing as i choose it as the first parameter, as shown in the first picture.

When i'm trying to save a view using legacy SQL, i don't get this error.